# Print string and not name from list (Python)

Tags: python

So here is my question:

```
a = "01000001"
b = "01000010"
c = "01000011"
# and so on...

code1 = "hello"
read1 = 0
list1 = []
while(read1 < len(code1)) :
    list1.append(code1[read1])
    read1 = read1 + 1
output1 = 0
while(output1 < len(list1)) :
    print(list1[output1], end="")
    output1 = output1 + 1
```

It will just print out `>>>hello`

How could I get python to print out the strings and not the names so we get:
`0100100001000101010001010100010101001111`

Comment: You realize a string like `"hello"` is already a sequence that supports iteration, right? You don't need to boostrap that on your own.

Comment: You are mixing up variable *names* (`a`, `b`, and so on) and the *contents* of a string (`"hello"`). That does not mix, in Python. Best start with [the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/); you may want to read all the way up to dictionaries and lists. (And there is a function to write out a number in binary.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way to turn string into binary.

```
st = 'hello'
print(' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in st))
```